# I am having trouble with inputing and displaying character at sepcific indices of a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello everyone I am currently working on a homework assignment where we have to prompt the user what object he wants to display (rectangle or triangle), then prompt the user for the height and width of the object.Finally we prompt the user for the x and y coordinates of where to start "drawing the object"
We make a "canvas" by using a [20][20] char array, and we use the array to store and later display the char in order to "draw" the object.

**Problem:** If I choose x=0 , y=0 for the user chosen coordinates everything works fine. If I choose any other value for x and y then the output is all blank. The code is below can anyone give a tip on what's going on? Thanks for the help.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Multidimensional {

public static char[][]canvas = new char[20][20];
public static int height, width, x, y;
public static char userChar;

public static void setRectangle()
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter height");
    height = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter Width");
    width = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter character");
    String input = kb.next();
    userChar = input.charAt(0);

    System.out.println("Enter location on canvas (x and y coordinate)");
    x = kb.nextInt();
    y = kb.nextInt();



    //loop for the rows
    for(int row=0; row<= height-1; row++){  

        //loop for the columns

        for(int column=0;column<=width-1;column++ ){ 

            canvas[row+y][column+x] = userChar; 
            //System.out.print("ROW+Y=   "   + (row+y));
            //System.out.print("    COLUMN+X=  " + (column+x));

        }


    }

    //displaying the array (for test purposes, not in final code)
    for(int row=0 ; row< 20; row++){

        for(int column=0; column <20; column++){


            System.out.print(canvas[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userChoice;
    Scanner kb =new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean userQuit = false;

    while(userQuit ==false){


    System.out.println("1. Type S to draw a rectangle.");
    System.out.println("2. Type T to draw a triangle.");
    System.out.println("3. Type D to display.");
    System.out.println("4. Type Q to quit.");
    userChoice = kb.next();

    if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
    {Multidimensional.setRectangle();
        }
    else if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
    {break;}

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What are your test values?  Have you tried height=1, width=1, offsetx=1, offsety=1?  The way your code is written the program will crash if height+offsety or width+offsetx is greater than 19.

Comment: Yeah, any value except for zero with x and y wont make it display.I have tried different values for height and width and as long as I keep  x and y equal two zero it displays correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But if you initialize your canvas array your problem will be solved.

Try this inside your main:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20 ;i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 20 ;j++)
        canvas[i][j]=' '; //or any character you like
```

p.s. careful with your x and y as you might get an indexOutOfBound error if you dont check that width+x and height+y are smaller than 20, because you are declaring canvas like this: `char[][]canvas = new char[20][20];` and not dynamically with the users input

Comment: I am aware of the indexOutOfBOund problems I was just trying it out for small values of x and y to test how the program was functioning. Thanks for reminding me though. I tried running the code I had on another computer and apparently it runs fine, so I guess the problem might have been with Eclipse on the computer.Thanks for your help and sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: Well I did run your code in my Eclipse and it worked as you said, only choosing 0 for x and y printed out the rectangle. And initializing canvas in main solved it for me :)